# The DynamicParameters Dbtype works fine even if the types don't match.[.net core]

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dapper

I think when I call function DynamicParameter.Add(), Dbtype is not works

I'm using Dapper when I connect to DB. I tried to request query to DB with below code

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@Uid", value: uId, dbType: DbType.string);
var sql = @"select * from User where Uid = @Uid";
```

The column **'Uid'** of **'User'** table is type of int. As you saw, I requested query with Uid parameter type of string. I expected it occurred error, however it worked well.

So I'd like to ask. DynamicParameter doesn't check parameter type when add data or run query? If so, why does Dbtype in DynamicParameter.Add() parameter exist?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dapper doesn't know a thing about your database. If you say it's a string, then that information is passed to the underlying SQL implementation and it's up to that to use the information. You would see the same behaviour with ADO.Net. Dapper is just the go-between.

Comment: @PalleDue Thank you for your reply. Then, I guess *DbType* is useless parameter so I don't know why this parameter exists. Could you or anyone share own opinion for this parameter?